# Chrome remote desktop for Linux

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I am trying to install Chrome Remote Desktop to my Linux machine so I can remote in from another computer. I have done this before on many other machines including on Windows and Mac; both of which worked exactly as one would expect.

However, when I go to install the Chrome Remote Desktop Host installer on Linux it downloads fine, then it opens in the software center and says:

> The package is of bad quality
>   The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could >cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided >this package file and include the details beneath.

I can click "OK" or "Ignore and Install." I went for the "Ignore and install" option. It seems to install, but when I go back to the tab in my Chrome browser that has the info about setting up the remote access it tells me it will work after I install the Chrome Remote Desktop Host installer. Which I just did.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried reinstalling it and it just worked. I didn't change anything.

Maybe there was an update to the installer?